# Integrals with Dirac delta functions in 3-D

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, dirac-delta

I've been trying to make sense of these two integrals, somehow the result seems intuitive, yet very hard to compute. We define

$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\delta(|x|-R)$$
and then note that
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\int\int\frac{f(x)f(y)}{|x-y|}=-\frac{1}{2R}$$
and

$$\int \frac{f(x)}{|x-y|}dx=\frac{1}{|y|}\quad \text{if }|y|\geq R$$

the integration is over $R^3$, and $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.
I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: I've rendered the image that you supplied in LaTex for better readability. Please add the integration variables to the second line, and make any further edits that will help clarify your question.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the first integral: $f$ has units of $\ell^{-1}$ ($\ell$: distance) whereas the differential as units of $\ell^6$, so the result should have units of $\ell^6 \times \ell^{-2} / \ell = \ell^3$, but the answer has units of $1/\ell$.

Comment: @caverac I'm unsure of what to think here. The original problem looks to be straight out of a textbook, but the first integral does not include the integration variables, which does not seem like something a textbook writer would omit. It is possible that the integral is wrong, but it is also possible that those units are accounted for by the constant out front, and are simply omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Since $R^2 \sin \theta \, d\theta d\phi$ can be viewed as an area element, integrating over $\boldsymbol x$ gives
$$g(\boldsymbol y) =
\frac 1 {4 \pi} \int_{\mathbb R^3}
 \frac {\delta(x - R)} {|\boldsymbol x - \boldsymbol y|} \, d\boldsymbol x =
\frac 1 {4 \pi} \int_{x = R}
 \frac {dS(\boldsymbol x)} {|\boldsymbol x - \boldsymbol y|} =
\frac 1 {4 \pi} \int_{x = R}
 \frac {dS(\boldsymbol x)} {|\boldsymbol x - (0, 0, y)|} = \\
R \, [y \leq R] + \frac {R^2} y \, [y > R].$$
As the result is continuous in $y$, we can also write
$$\frac 1 {4 \pi} \int_{\mathbb R^3}
 \delta(y - R) \, g(\boldsymbol y) \, d\boldsymbol y =
\frac 1 {4 \pi} \int_{y = R} g(\boldsymbol y) \, dS(\boldsymbol y) = R^3.$$

Answer (score 0):

> **WARNING**: I am aware this is not the actual solution to the problem, but it may give you ideas.

I am going to call $|{\bf x}| = x$, it is relatively straightforward to show that

$$
|{\bf x} - {\bf y}| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - 2 xy\cos(\theta - \theta')}
$$

where $\theta$ is the polar angle of ${\bf x}$, and $\theta'$ is the polar angle of ${\bf y}$. With this in mind

\begin{eqnarray}
\int {\rm d}^3{\bf x}~{\rm d}^3{\bf y} \frac{f({\bf x}) f({\bf y})}{|{\bf x} - {\bf y}|} &=&
\frac{1}{(4\pi)^2}\int {\rm d}\cos\theta ~{\rm d}\phi ~{\rm d}x~ x^2 \int {\rm d}\cos\theta' ~{\rm d}\phi' ~{\rm d}y~ y^2 \frac{\delta(x - R)\delta(y - R)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - 2 xy\cos(\theta - \theta')}} \\
&=& \frac{(2\pi)(4\pi)R^4}{(4\pi)^2}\int {\rm d}\cos(\theta - \theta') \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2 + R^2 - 2R^2 \cos(\theta - \theta')}} \\
&=& \frac{R^3}{2\sqrt{2}} \int_{-1}^{+1}{\rm d}z \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - z}} = \frac{R^3}{8}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you for your reply, what I did was trying to evaluate the second integral using spherical coordinates, then using it to evaluate the first. However, I was confused, as I used the Jacobian for the spherical coordinates, but they seem to multiply by 4π for some reason.

Comment: The first formula is not true though. Consider $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ on a circle in the $Oxy$ plane. Clearly the distance depends on the $\phi$ angles.